# Error connecting to my sql connector. I am trying to connect to the database , credentials in comments , but i am getting error

Tags: python, mysql

```
import pdvega 
import pandas as pd 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
 
 
# Connecting from the server
# conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'beat_dq_readonly',
#                                host = '35.187.158.251',
#                               database = 'beat_results_dev',
#                                 password = 'Gspann@123')


db_connection_str = 'mysql+pymysql://beat_dq_readonly:Gspann@123@35.187.158.251/beat_results_dev'

db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM vw_dv_count_rpt', con=db_connection)
```

I am not able to connect , It gives me error
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '123@35.187.158.251' ([Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your password contains `@` character. You can use `quote_plus` to resolve the issue :

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_connection_str = f'mysql+pymysql://beat_dq_readonly:{quote_plus("Gspann@123")}@35.187.158.251/beat_results_dev'
```

Comment: So I guess you can mark it as answer